# How to set the value of another <input> onfocusout of an <input>

Tags: focus

I am using the following html for feeding user name and on losing the focus want the email input field to fill up with username + '@gmail.com'. But the Value setting is not giving the desired result.

HTML code is

```
<div class="form-group" >
                <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span></span>
                    <input type="text" name="name" onfocusout= "seteMail(this)" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Personal Number as User Name" maxlength="7" value="<?php echo $name ?>" required/>

                    <span class="text-danger"><?php echo $nameError; ?></span>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span></span>
                    <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter AFNET eMail ID" maxlength="40" value="<?php echo $email ?>" required/>

                <span class="text-danger"><?php echo $emailError; ?></span>
                </div>
            </div>
```

javascript is

```
function seteMail(thisvalue) {
            //  window.alert(thisvalue.value);

                var tempval = thisvalue.value.toString()+'@gmail.com';
                 $('#email').val(tempval);  
                 $('#email').html(tempval); 
            };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<input>` is an input field and can never be set externally as it takes input only from the Standard Input that is Keyboard.

I have realised this after lots of H&T Method (H&TM).